Can the size of a force field be manipulated?
I cant seem to find if there is a way that you can manipulate the size of the sphere force field/the area it affecs.
I am doing a similar project like this tutorial and I want to affect just a small portion of the cloth around the object, while having a very strong pull around the object
Is there a way to change it?

It's there, as an option for the force field.
Take a look.

